# Avoiding Cartesian product on sql query

Tags: sql, cartesian-product

I got a cartesian product but can't find a way to prevent it...

I tried to simplify my query to the strict minimum :

```
select
    SUM(tableA.amount) as "Total Amount"
from
    tableA,
    tableB,
where
    tableA.id= 12 and
    tableB.id= 10
```

The problem here is that tableB has 3 resulting rows so the total amount is added 3 times (cause of result from tableB). I can't figure out how to specify that I just want the last result from tableB, I guess that would solve the problem.

**table A : id | amount**

**table B :
id | date | comment**

EDIT: I commented but might have added it on the original post: I need that tableB on my query (can't remove it) and the difference between each row returned by this tableB is the date column

Comment: I think you need to provide more of your requirement, rather than just the bare minimum.  You suggest using the 'last' row from tableB, but there is no 'last' value.  Perhaps you meant using 'just one of the rows since they are all the same'.  If that's the case then you might want to use inline views to filter the target rows on tableB

Comment: @Praem . . . You have oversimplified the problem.  Your calculation does not use `tableB` at all, so you can just remove it from this query.

Comment: I understand your point but this is a sql-based problem. I need that tableB but the problem is not there, it's that if tableB retrieves X rows, my total amount will be added X times cause of it. I just need to find a way to prevent my tableB from returning more than 1 row based on a single select and knowing that the difference between rows returned by tableB is the date column...

Comment: Still, your example shows no usage at all of tableB. Please edit your request, so your example shows what you want to do with tableB. The solution depends on this. Do you want to show the latest comment inyour results? What DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, ...) are you using? The solution also depends on this.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what's the point of explaining the purpose of tableB....
If you take that exact sql query I gave and try it, if tableB returns more than one result the total amount will be added X times there are rows returned by tableB. 

This is a simple SQL Cartesian product and has nothing to do with my query or tableB purpose on this query. 
I just needed to find a way to always return one row from tableB, the one with the most recent date (cause I guessed that would work), that's why I tried what I posted on my answer below... May I ask your opinion about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help I got, I might have found a way to solve my problem. May I ask if this looks ok ?

I had this

```
select
    SUM(tableA.amount) as "Total Amount"
from
    tableA,
    tableB,
where
    tableA.id= 12 and
    tableB.id= 10
```

And I tried this cause the date is the only difference on my rows returned by tableB, that seems to work...

```
select
        SUM(tableA.amount) as "Total Amount"
    from
        tableA,
        tableB,
    where
        tableA.id= 12 and
        tableB.id= 10 and
        not exists(select 
                      1 
                   from 
                      tableB b 
                   where 
                      b.date > tableB.date and 
                      b.id = tableB.id
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really doing a Cartesian product.  Or, you are, but with one row in each table.  Performance is not an issue.

I might be inclined to write the query as:

```
select SUM(a.amount) as Total_Amount
from (select a.* from tableA a where a.id = 12) a cross join
     (select b.* from tableB b where b.id = 10) b;
```

This emphasizes that you are doing a Cartesian product but presumably on only one row from each table.

You can simplify the calculation to:

```
select SUM(a.amount)  as Total_Amount
from tableA a
where a.id = 12;
```

Comment: I read the original post such that b.id is not unique - tableB has three rows where id = 10

Comment: The difference between each row is the date. I got 3 rows with the same ID but with 3 different dates. I need that table on the query cause she's linked to an other table that is not needed here. The amounts are only from tableA but are x3 cause of tableB which brings more than 1 result. That's why I said maybe getting one result from tableB would solve the problem. (the most recent date for example)

Comment: If you want to filter the results according tableB, why don't you provide another where clause for that, or ordering and limiting the results of the second `select` statement that @Gordon provide, perhaps like this (`...(select b.* from tableB b where b.id = 10 order by date limit 1)...`)